# Slim Framework Installation failing due to PHP version not greater or equal to, though it is

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I have a VPS Running Plesk, which Plesk has a hard requirement for PHP 5.4.x That said through some apache magic. Plesk is able to let me install additional PHP versions new, current, and edge and run those in environments I choose.

The problem I am facing is `php -v` shows the globally installed php, from which composer fails to install Slim Framework due to the min. req. being 5.5.0. That said if I run `phpinfo();` in the same directory I want to install in I get 5.5.30

So I am here seeing if there is any safe workaround I can deploy for the time being that will allow me to maintain the ability to install using composer, as I like to keep all my dependancies in line best as I possibly can

Comment: A little more digging cause I am impatient and I have come across https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform which may be the answer I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

From the composer docs:

> --ignore-platform-reqs: ignore php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-* requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these. See also the platform config option.